# Apache Tomcat is not finishing startup after deployed in Minikube - Kubernetes

Tags: apache, tomcat, docker, kubernetes, minikube

I am trying to deploy a tomcat docker container in the Kubernetes and start the application deployed.

I have installed tomcat inside the docker container and copied my application war file in the tomcat webapps folder. When i ssh into the docker container and tried to start the tomcat server by running the catalina.sh file, tomcat server started deploying my app.war file and stayed there. Tomcat server is not finish starting up. 
 I tried looking at the logs, but did not help much to track down this issue. I tried deploying the same war file in the docker, it worked perfectly there.

Note: When i restart the minikube, i can see that tomcat tried to deploy the war and also tried to start the server as well. But when i restart the tomcat by navigating to the /tomcat/bin folder and running the catalina.sh start, tomcat server just deployed the war file and not starting up the server.

Here is what the catalina.out looks like

```
Jan 30, 2018 4:06:09 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-8080"]
Jan 30, 2018 4:06:09 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
Jan 30, 2018 4:06:09 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 854 ms
Jan 30, 2018 4:06:09 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jan 30, 2018 4:06:09 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.82
Jan 30, 2018 4:06:09 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployWAR
INFO: Deploying web application archive /usr/local/tomcat/webapps/app.war
```

I appreciate any help on this ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was happening because of lack of memory for the Node. In my case it is Minikube which is acting as a Node. After i allotted more memory to minikube, i am able to deploy and start my application from tomcat docker container.